# Automatically prefix undefined methods by `Math.` when using the built-in JavaScript engine?

Tags: java, math, expression, evaluation

To evaluate a mathematical expression given in a String, I'm using the built-in JavaScript engine as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3423360/1225328):

```java
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
double result = (Double) engine.eval("Math.min(2, 4)");
// result: 2.0
```

It would be great if every function that belongs to `Math` (`min`, `max`, `pow`...) could be written without the `Math.` prefix, to lighten the expressions:

```java
double result = (Double) engine.eval("min(2, 4)");
```

For now, I get the following exception:

```
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "min" is not defined (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1
```

Is there anyway to get this improvement done? For example, every time the exception gets catched, try to prefix the undefined reference by `Math.` and re-evaluate the expression? I've not been able to find how to proceed.

I tried to used the `engine.put("min", ...)` method, in vain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to do something like

```
engine.eval("min = Math.min");
...

double result = (Double) engine.eval("min(2, 4)");
```

Comment: I was afraid there were to many functions to register one after the other, but [actually not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math). Thanks ;)